# seperate graphs for dashboad style report report builder 3 grouping

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

Need help.

I have a dashboard style report with eight different graphs on it. My goal is to let that report run for every instance separate.

Just for a better understanding a simple example.

A Supermarket offers the following articles: vegetables, fruits, drinks etc. <-- first parameter.
dependent on the first parameter you have selection range. f.e. vegetabels --> bananas, apples, oranges etc. <-- second parameter

I want to run the report via a data driven subscription. Means I want to create separate reports for the articles (which I define in the subscription)  which include the graphs separated by the instances (apples, bananas, etc.). I would like to get separate graphs. I don't want that data in one graph.

I tried to force the tables in to a matrix but this didn't work.

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean to say these 8 graphs are exactly the same but with different instances or all instances on each graph showing different data? Also are your instances always 8 i.e. always needing 8 graphs?

Comment: I must admit that I don't understand what you want. try to re-phrase your exsample or provide some sketch to support your explenation. that way we can help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to use sub reports. Using these you can create separate reports and using the sub reports function to tie them together. These work well for me.

Example  see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581.aspx